# What can I do to get rid of the error message: "The DSM service was delayed by 2409807 seconds for a driver query/download/install on device '...'"?

Tags: windows-update, drivers, windows-8.1

My little laptop runs with MS-Windows 8 and I am not getting windows updates anymore.

I looked all day for a solution and so far came up empty handed. All the solutions proposed do not explain what could really be wrong. I tried to delete the "database" that's used to know what was updated (the `SoftwareDistribution` folder) and rebooted a few times after some other attempts, but nothing bypasses what is currently blocking the installation.

One thing, though, when I search on the word "install" in the Event Viewer, is this entry:

> The DSM service was delayed by 2409807 seconds for a driver query/download/install on device 'HID\VID_1267&PID_0210\6&4CB481F&0&0000'

"DSM" stands for *Device Setup Manager* and I found a few messages about this specific message, but so far I have not yet understood how I could fix that problem on my computer. I have been using my computer behind my Linux firewall for not much else than watching a few videos, so it did not matter much that I did not get the updates. However, now I'd like to get those again as I want to be able to go out in the wild with that computer.

As you can see, the DSM has blocked installations from happening for 2,409,807 seconds. That's a fairly long time (about 27.89 days.) It does not look like it's going to fix itself any time soon either.

Any idea what can be done to fix this problem? I tried refreshing the driver (HID/VID-1267&PID_0210 is the mouse driver,) but that did not help.

The following is the content of WindowsUpdate.log after a reboot. I tried to start the update and it just sat there, as usual. I do not really see anything that I would consider helpful...

```
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 AU  Initiating Install-at-shutdown
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 Shutdwn Checking to see whether install at shutdown is appropriate
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 Shutdwn user declined update at shutdown
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 AU  AU initiates service shutdown
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    9c8 Agent     * WARNING: Failed to filter search results, error = 0x8024000B
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 AU  ###########  AU: Uninitializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 WuTask  Uninit WU Task Manager
2017-02-21  22:31:23:347     948    850 WuTask  ScheduledInstallTaskHandler, setting scheduled install attempt time to 2017-02-24 05:09:28, using automatic maintenance:True.
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    9c8 Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    9c8 Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdatesWuApp  Id = 4]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    9c8 Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    9c8 IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 4, operation # 48) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    9c8 IdleTmr Decremented idle timer priority operation counter to 2
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   ***  END  ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = Windows Defender (77BDAF73-B396-481F-9042-AD358843EC24)  Id = 5]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = Windows Defender (77BDAF73-B396-481F-9042-AD358843EC24)  Id = 5]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * Criteria = "(IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0 and CategoryIDs contains '8c3fcc84-7410-4a95-8b89-a166a0190486' and CategoryIDs contains 'e0789628-ce08-4437-be74-2495b842f43b')"
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * RegisterService is set
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc EP  Got 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 redir Client/Server URL: "https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx"
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * WARNING: Search call was cancelled with context 2
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x8024000B
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = Windows Defender (77BDAF73-B396-481F-9042-AD358843EC24)  Id = 5]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x8024000b
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 5, operation # 64) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    2fc IdleTmr Decremented idle timer priority operation counter to 1
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   ***  END  ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = ChkWuDrv  Id = 6]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = ChkWuDrv  Id = 6]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * Criteria = "Type='Driver' and DriverMatch='Best' and DeviceInstance='HID\SYN1B7B&COL01\5&36D1A07C&0&0000'"
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-21-3371382042-70944851-1960853716-1001
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * RegisterService is set
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c EP  Got 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 redir Client/Server URL: "https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx"
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * WARNING: Search call was cancelled with context 2
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x8024000B
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = ChkWuDrv  Id = 6]
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x8024000b
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 6, operation # 71) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2017-02-21  22:31:23:456     948    a7c IdleTmr Decremented idle timer priority operation counter to 0
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   WARNING: WU client fails to call back to search call {5DE8180C-CE34-429E-BE1F-0FDDAF603714} with error 0x800706ba
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   WARNING: WU client fails to call back to search call {0369E560-5E7C-4CD3-8E68-01B957052DDB} with error 0x800706ba
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Agent   Sending shutdown notification to client
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 Report  CWERReporter finished handling 1 events. (00000000)
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU  Found invalid timer to remove:
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU      Timer: 117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782, Expires 2017-02-22 06:23:57, not idle-only, network-only
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU  Found invalid timer to remove:
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU      Timer: 31DA7559-FE27-4810-8FF6-987195B1FD98, Expires 2017-02-22 01:38:00, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU  Earliest future timer found: 
2017-02-21  22:31:23:691     948    850 AU      Timer: CF1ABEC6-7887-4964-BB93-B2E21B31CEC1, Expires 2017-02-22 23:31:22, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:31:23:847     948    850 AU  Earliest future timer found: 
2017-02-21  22:31:23:847     948    850 AU      Timer: CF1ABEC6-7887-4964-BB93-B2E21B31CEC1, Expires 2017-02-22 23:31:22, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:31:24:160     948    850 Service *********
2017-02-21  22:31:24:160     948    850 Service **  END  **  Service: Service exit [Exit code = 0x240001]
2017-02-21  22:31:24:160     948    850 Service *************
2017-02-21  22:32:00:040     928    880 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.9.9600.18235, tz: -0800)  ===========
2017-02-21  22:32:00:056     928    880 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe
2017-02-21  22:32:00:056     928    880 Misc      = Module: c:\windows\system32\wuaueng.dll
2017-02-21  22:32:00:040     928    880 Service *************
2017-02-21  22:32:00:056     928    880 Service ** START **  Service: Service startup
2017-02-21  22:32:00:056     928    880 Service *********
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 IdleTmr Non-AoAc machine.  Aoac operations will be ignored.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Agent     * WU client version 7.9.9600.18235
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Agent   WARNING: SleepStudyTracker: Machine is non-AOAC. Sleep study tracker disabled.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Agent     * Base directory: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Agent     * Access type: No proxy
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:759     928    880 Agent     * Network state: Disconnected
2017-02-21  22:32:03:806     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:806     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing global settings cache  ***********
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent     * Endpoint Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent     * WSUS server: <NULL>
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent     * WSUS status server: <NULL>
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent     * Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2017-02-21  22:32:03:978     928    880 Agent     * Windows Update access disabled: No
2017-02-21  22:32:04:322     928    880 WuTask  WuTaskManager delay initialize completed successfully..
2017-02-21  22:32:04:322     928    880 AU      Timer: CF1ABEC6-7887-4964-BB93-B2E21B31CEC1, Expires 2017-02-22 23:31:22, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:32:04:322     928    880 AU      Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2017-02-22 23:31:22, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:32:04:322     928    880 AU      Timer: E25CADF6-86A6-4569-BCDF-89BE66B0CA66, Expires 2017-02-25 01:34:55, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:32:06:384     928    880 Report  WARNING: CSerializationHelper:: InitSerialize failed : 0x80070002
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 Report  CWERReporter::Init succeeded
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 Agent   ***********  Agent: Initializing Windows Update Agent  ***********
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 DnldMgr Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU  ###########  AU: Initializing Automatic Updates  ###########
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2017-02-22 06:32:06
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU  AIR Mode is disabled
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU    # Approval type: Pre-install notify (User preference)
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU    # Auto-install minor updates: No (User preference)
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU    # ServiceTypeDefault: Service 117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782 Approval type: (Scheduled)
2017-02-21  22:32:06:603     928    880 AU    # Will interact with non-admins (Non-admins are elevated (User preference))
2017-02-21  22:32:11:494     928    880 AU  WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80070490
2017-02-21  22:32:11:525     928    880 AU  IsPerUserUpdateInstallableForAnyLoggedOnUser, found at least 1 logged on user for which the update 7BC92AC0-516C-429D-AAFD-2CFC391C4CBF, revision 1 is applicable
2017-02-21  22:32:11:822     928    880 AU  AU finished delayed initialization
2017-02-21  22:32:12:165     928    880 AU  Processing post-reboot results now.
2017-02-21  22:32:12:165     928    880 AU  Obtained Post reboot hr from Agent:8024000c
2017-02-21  22:32:12:165     928    880 AU  Currently AUX is enabled - so not show any WU Upgrade notifications.
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  IsPerUserUpdateInstallableForAnyLoggedOnUser, found at least 1 logged on user for which the update 7BC92AC0-516C-429D-AAFD-2CFC391C4CBF, revision 1 is applicable
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  Triggering Offline detection (non-interactive)
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  Adding timer: 
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU      Timer: 31DA7559-FE27-4810-8FF6-987195B1FD98, Expires 2017-02-22 06:32:12, not idle-only, not network-only
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  Currently AUX is enabled - so not show any WU Upgrade notifications.
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  IsPerUserUpdateInstallableForAnyLoggedOnUser, found at least 1 logged on user for which the update 7BC92AC0-516C-429D-AAFD-2CFC391C4CBF, revision 1 is applicable
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 2.
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    f08 DnldMgr Asking handlers to reconcile their sandboxes
2017-02-21  22:32:12:181     928    880 AU  #############
2017-02-21  22:32:15:462     928    880 AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2017-02-21  22:32:15:462     928    880 AU  #########
2017-02-21  22:32:15:462     928    880 IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 1) started; operation # 16; does not use network; is at background priority
2017-02-21  22:32:16:759     928    880 Report  ***********  Report: Initializing static reporting data  ***********
2017-02-21  22:32:16:759     928    880 Report    * OS Version = 6.3.9600.0.0.66304
2017-02-21  22:32:16:759     928    880 Report    * OS Product Type = 0x00000065
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Computer Brand = Acer
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Computer Model = Aspire R3-471T
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Platform Role = 2
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * AlwaysOn/AlwaysConnected (AOAC) = 0
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Revision = V1.09
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Name = V1.09
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Release Date = 2015-05-20T00:00:00
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Sku Number = Aspire R3-471T_0899_1_09
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Vendor = Insyde Corp.
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Family = BDW
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Major Release = 0
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Bios Minor Release = 0
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Report    * Locale ID = 1033
2017-02-21  22:32:16:775     928    880 Handler Calculating current update level for this session
2017-02-21  22:32:21:359     928    880 Handler UH: Current cumulative update level calculated: package identity Package_for_KB3000850~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.8, display name KB3000850, support URL http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3000850, timestamp 01d005a4c1b543a3
2017-02-21  22:32:21:359     928    880 Handler Done calculating current update level for this session
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 Agent   *** START ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 1]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {EAF7374D-5A71-4CC0-B58E-60AF7DAF39C9} ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 Agent   SkipSelfUpdateCheck search flag set for serverId: 117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 2) started; operation # 18; does not use network; is at background priority
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 Agent   *** START ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 2]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {9EAA0A82-DFD9-4C4D-BC81-4247D83AC9EE} ServiceId = {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782}]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    880 Service UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    1260    Agent   ***  END  ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 1]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:453     928    1268    Agent   ***  END  ***  Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 2]
2017-02-21  22:32:21:906     928    1260    Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:32:22:047     928    1268    Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:32:22:063     928    1260    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 1]
2017-02-21  22:32:22:094     928    1268    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 2]
2017-02-21  22:32:22:203     928    1260    Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:32:22:234     928    1268    Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:32:22:234     928    1260    Agent     * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2017-02-21  22:32:22:250     928    1268    Agent     * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2017-02-21  22:32:22:281     928    1260    Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2017-02-21  22:32:22:297     928    1268    Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2017-02-21  22:32:22:344     928    1260    Agent     * ServiceID = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} Windows Update
2017-02-21  22:32:22:359     928    1268    Agent     * ServiceID = {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} Third party service
2017-02-21  22:32:22:438     928    1260    Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine & All Users}
2017-02-21  22:32:22:453     928    1268    Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine & All Users}
2017-02-21  22:32:22:641     928    1260    Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2017-02-21  22:32:22:750     928    1268    Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-18
2017-02-21  22:32:28:625     928    1268    Agent     * Added update {7BC92AC0-516C-429D-AAFD-2CFC391C4CBF}.1 to search result
2017-02-21  22:32:28:750     928    1268    Agent     * Found 1 updates and 56 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 141 out of 317 deployed entities
2017-02-21  22:32:29:297     928    1268    Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:32:29:360     928    1268    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 2]
2017-02-21  22:32:29:406     928    1268    Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:32:29:578     928    1268    IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 3) started; operation # 19; does not use network; is at background priority
2017-02-21  22:32:29:656     928    1268    Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:32:29:672     928    1268    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 3]
2017-02-21  22:32:29:735     928    1268    Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:32:29:735     928    1268    Agent     * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2017-02-21  22:32:29:797     928    1268    Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2017-02-21  22:32:29:813     928    1268    Agent     * ServiceID = {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} Third party service
2017-02-21  22:32:29:828     928    1268    Agent     * Search Scope = {Current User}
2017-02-21  22:32:29:828     928    1268    Agent     * Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-21-3371382042-70944851-1960853716-1001
2017-02-21  22:32:31:063     928    1268    Agent     * Added update {7BC92AC0-516C-429D-AAFD-2CFC391C4CBF}.1 to search result
2017-02-21  22:32:31:156     928    1268    Agent     * Found 1 updates and 56 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 141 out of 317 deployed entities
2017-02-21  22:32:31:172     928    1268    Agent   *********
2017-02-21  22:32:31:188     928    1268    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates  Id = 3]
2017-02-21  22:32:31:203     928    1268    Agent   *************
2017-02-21  22:32:31:203     928    1268    IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 3, operation # 19) stopped; does not use network; is at background priority
2017-02-21  22:32:31:235     928    1268    IdleTmr WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 2, operation # 18) stopped; does not use network; is at background priority
2017-02-21  22:32:31:328     928    13d0    AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {9EAA0A82-DFD9-4C4D-BC81-4247D83AC9EE} ServiceId = {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782}]
2017-02-21  22:32:31:344     928    13d0    AU    # 1 updates detected
2017-02-21  22:32:31:391     928    13d0    AU  #########
2017-02-21  22:32:31:391     928    13d0    AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {9EAA0A82-DFD9-4C4D-BC81-4247D83AC9EE} ServiceId = {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782}]
2017-02-21  22:32:31:469     928    13d0    AU  #############
2017-02-21  22:32:33:422     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9CC3&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_03
2017-02-21  22:32:33:453     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:453     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C96&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_E3
2017-02-21  22:32:33:453     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:469     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1604&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_09
2017-02-21  22:32:33:485     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180000a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:500     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device USB\VID_8087&PID_07DC&REV_0001
2017-02-21  22:32:33:516     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:516     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C94&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_E3
2017-02-21  22:32:33:516     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:531     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9CA2&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_03
2017-02-21  22:32:33:531     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x1802000, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:531     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9C90&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_E3
2017-02-21  22:32:33:531     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:531     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9CBA&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_03
2017-02-21  22:32:33:547     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:32:33:563     928    1260    Driver  Matched driver to device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9CA6&SUBSYS_08991025&REV_03
2017-02-21  22:32:33:578     928    1260    Driver  Status: 0x180200a, ProblemNumber: 00000000
2017-02-21  22:33:58:392     928    6c0 IdleTmr Incremented idle timer priority operation counter to 1
2017-02-21  22:33:58:767     928    6c0 AU  Triggering AU detection through DetectNow API
2017-02-21  22:33:58:767     928    6c0 AU  Additional Service {117CAB2D-82B1-4B5A-A08C-4D62DBEE7782} with Approval type {Scheduled} added to AU services list
2017-02-21  22:33:58:767     928    6c0 AU  Will do the detection after current detection completes
2017-02-21  22:39:20:475     928    12bc    IdleTmr Decremented idle timer priority operation counter to 0
```

Comment: `I tried to delete the "database" that's used to know what was updated` - What database are you referring to? The SoftwareDistribution folder? `I tried refreshing the driver, but that did not help` - What driver? Have you looked at the WindowsUpdate.log log file?

Comment: I updated the question about the database (yes SoftwareDistribution) and driver (Mouse).

Comment: The WindowsUpdate log file should give you some clue as to what's happening.

Comment: @joeqwerty, There is the log file from my last reboot. Nothing much if you ask me. But maybe I'm missing something or not understanding some of the messages.

Comment: @joeqwerty I actually found a solution to my problem which was to turn off the auto-installation of devices. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found a page with the solution. Of course, it does not look like that answer has anything to do with the installation, but it clearly is. The DSM is blocked because in its head, no matter what, it has to take care of that device installation. If the device driver cannot be found, it asks the install manager (which is shared with the Automatic Windows Updates) to pause. That happens again and again... and prevents any other proper installation.

First, go your **Devices and Printers** window

[image]

Once there, right click on the device that is causing problems. In my case. it was the computer itself. The menu will show an option named **Device Installation Settings**.

[image]

That menu takes you to a preferences window which says:

> "automatically install stuff for you (even if I cannot do that and will block all other installations from happening until you find this window, ha! ha! ha!)"

*(Sorry! It looks like I read between the lines there...)*

Change the selection like follow:

[image]

Click **Save Changes** and if you are having the same problem as I (i.e. the DSM says it will delay and does that over and over again) then just that will wake up the Auto-Updates.

Also, if you see devices you have no clue about and are sure you are not using, you may also want to uninstall them as you're at it.

For reference, the article at MS-Windows can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2500967/how-to-stop-windows-7-automatically-installing-drivers